# How can I embed a base14 font in a pdf

Tags: apache-fop

I'm using FOP 0.94 I might be able to upgrade to FOP 0.95. 
Is it possible to embed base14 fonts? If so, how?

I have tried putting this in the fop.xconf:

```
<font-metrics type="TYPE1">
<font-name>Times-Roman</font-name>
<embed/>
</font-metrics>
```

That didn't work.

Best regards, 
Morten

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19767205/embedding-font-into-apache-fop/38127845#38127845

Answer (score 0):

I choose to upgrade to FOP 1.1. A lot of issues went away.

Comment: The answer is to buy the font and have it on hand to embed. The base 14 fonts (Helvetica, Times, Courier in normal, bold, italic/oblique and bold-italic/oblique, Zapf Dingbats and Symbol) are not free. You must but them from their source of you wish to embed them into a document. Most all formatters only have the font sizing information so that they can format the documents, the display/print of which is handled by the application that has the actual font information and not metrics.