# Embedded font don't work in Apache FOP

Tags: java, apache, fonts, apache-fop

I am using FOP to tranform xml to pdf, and I need to use Chinese characters.I did do something to use Chinese font,but it seems don't work at all.
I create the font xml file.

[image]

and registered in the fop.xconf

```
<font metrics-url="/home/zhufree/Tools/fop-2.1/conf/simkai.xml" kerning="yes" embed-url="/home/zhufree/Tools/fop-2.1/conf/kaiti.ttf">
   <font-triplet name="simkai" style="normal" weight="normal" />
   <font-triplet name="simkai" style="normal" weight="bold" />
   <font-triplet name="simkai" style="italic" weight="normal" />
   <font-triplet name="simkai" style="italic" weight="bold" />
</font>
```

the font xml file and font ttf file are in the same directory with fop.xconf,when I try to transform,it still show me cant find the font.

[image]

What should I do to show the Chinese character?

Update：
I solved the problem by using specific configuration file in java code, and it worked well.Thanks.

Comment: Supposing you set `font-family="simkai"` in a suitable position, so that it applies to your chinese text, it seems **you are not telling FOP to use your configuration file**: you should call it with the `-c` parameter, for example: `fop -c /path/to/your/fop.xconf test.fo test.pdf` (by the way, if you are using a recent version of FOP the xml metrics file is not needed any more)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache FOP Displaying ### with SunSim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25895984/apache-fop-displaying-with-sunsim)

Comment: Can you share portion of your configuration java code and post it as an answer?