# FOP Apache upgrade from 1.0 to 2.3 : missing method setFontBaseURL

Tags: apache-fop

I'm trying to upgrade my FOP library to 2.3 but it seems it changed a lot.

The only thing I can't figure out is how to set the font base url. In the past it was like this:

```
fopFactory.getFontManager().setFontBaseURL(url);
```

Does anyone have an idea how to do it?

Comment: Perhaps this will help you 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51258443/polish-letters-in-using-apache-fop/51259172?noredirect=1#comment89497218_51259172

Comment: I already checked that. What I really need is to set it in the code, since the url can be different in a few use-cases.